# YUI remove javascript comments

Tags: javascript, comments, yui-compressor

I need to remove comments (the "// This is a comment" like comments) from some Javascript code, I'm using YUI compressor, there is an option to do that?

Thanks

---

Thanks for the response, I'm trying to merge several scripts and after compress with YUI; I've found if I compress and then merge the scripts it works, but if I merge and then compress, something goes wrong and I got a broken script

Comment: I merge then compress in my project and it works just fine. Do your scripts rely on lots of global variables and global functions? Maybe that's creating a problem for the compressor.  How is it "broken"?

Comment: the recommended way is to MINIFY each file first, then combine them secondly. Not the other way around. Is there any reason why you can't Minify then Combine?

Comment: @Pure.Krome Could you explain why it's recommended to minify before combining? I have an [active question on this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746313/when-using-the-yui-compressor-should-i-combine-then-minify-or-minify-then-comb)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

YUI Compressor removes comments by default. You have to use a special comment format to *keep* comments.

```
/*! This comment will not be removed, so it's a good place to put a copyright */

// this comment will be removed

/* this one too */
```

Comment: it is removing only `//` comments all `/*` comments are not removed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20831597/how-to-remove-comments-with-bundletransformer-yuijsminifier