# How to remove comments with BundleTransformer YuiJsMinifier

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, bundling-and-minification, yui-compressor, bundletransformer

I am using [BundleTransformer](http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com) to minify `css` and `js` resources

```
        <yui>
            <css compressionType="Standard" removeComments="true" lineBreakPosition="-1" />
            <js compressionType="Standard" obfuscateJavascript="true" preserveAllSemicolons="false" disableOptimizations="false" ignoreEval="false" severity="0" lineBreakPosition="-1" encoding="UTF8" threadCulture="en-us" />
        </yui>
```

As you can see for `css` it is possible to specify `removeComments="true"`
But in `js` there is no such option.

I red that YUI js compressor [removes comments by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547976/yui-remove-javascript-comments). Yes it is kind of removes, but it is still leave comments like that:

```
/* NUGET: BEGIN LICENSE TEXT
 *
 *Bla bla bla
 *
 * NUGET: END LICENSE TEXT */

/*!
 * Bla
 * Licensed under http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 */
```

Looks like there is no way to force YIU js minifier to remove comments.

https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor :

> C-style comments starting with /*! are preserved. This is useful with
>   comments containing copyright/license information

Is there anything I can do by using [BundleTransformer](http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com) to completely remove all kind of comments in bundled minified output files? [Google page speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) strongly recommended me to do that.

Answer (score 1):

YUI compressor does not support removing of important comments.

I recommend you to install [BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax](http://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax/) package. Thereafter register `MicrosoftAjaxCssMinifier` and `MicrosoftAjaxJsMinifier` as default minifiers, and add to the Web.config file the following configuration settings:

```
<configuration>
    …
    <bundleTransformer xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BundleTransformer.Configuration.xsd">
        …
        <microsoftAjax>
            <css commentMode="None" />
            <js preserveImportantComments="false" />
        </microsoftAjax>
        …
    </bundleTransformer>
    …
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's yuicompressor version 2.4.8, but the issue is still there.

If you are on linux, you can use **sed** command to replace `/*!` with `/*` in the file before running it through yuicompressor.

Real-life working example that I've just tested:

```
sed -i -e "s/\/\*\!/\/\*/g" script.js
```

`\/` - escaped symbol `/`

`\*` - escaped symbol `*`

`\!` - escaped symbol `!`

`g` - global (regular expression flag)

`s` - substitute (regular expression flag)

`-i` - "inplace" command flag which means replacing on the fly (applying changes on the same file)

Next step: just run the yuicompressor as usual and voilà!

```
java -jar /path/to/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar script.js -o script.min.js --charset utf-8
```